# Disable accelerometer tilt in Cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am currently creating an app that uses the accelerometer to move an image around in space. Right now the image moves when you shake or tilt the phone. I want it to just move on a shake though and I can't figure out how to disable the tilt. Is this possible? How might I go about doing this?

I am currently running motion.js plugin for physics simulation. 
As far as I know, this is the only part of the code linking to the accelerometers. Even when I try to define the alpha, beta, and gamma values it continues to return orientation values. Ideas?

JS :

```
window.ondevicemotion = function(event){
  ax = event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x * 0.2;
};

window.ondeviceorientation = function(event) {
  console.log("tilting");
  event.gamma = 0
  event.alpha = 0
  event.beta = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the difference between a shake and a tilt as far as an accelerometer is concerned is that the tilt is gradual while a shake is violent. You should implement some thresh-holds to check if the values change quickly enough to be considered a shake.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a shot. Thanks for the response.